# Is there a way to override the constructor in Moo?

Tags: perl, moo

I am working on a MooX module that needs to add a wrapper around the constructor.

I've tried method modifies or having the import method directly change `*{"${target}::new"}` with no effect.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Why can't you use BUILD?

Comment: Because I want to override whether it even returns an object of that type. It's a Moo version of [MooseX::Failover](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Failover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, around does work:

```
package MyRole;
use Moo::Role

around new => sub { ... };
```

but the role that has the around needs to be consumed *after* attributes are added, e.g.

```
package MyClass;
use Moo;

has attr1 => (... );
with 'MyRole';
```